# PT Checkboxes returning label instead of value

Tags: add-on, pixelandtonic, pt-checkboxes

ExpressionEngine 2.5.3
PT Fieldpack 1.0.3
Matrix 2.4.3

Maybe I'm going crazy, but PT Checkboxes seems to be showing labels for the value instead of the value. My {winner} fieldtype is structured like this:

one : 1st Place
two : 2nd Place
three : 3rd Place

It shows like this in the Publish form:

x 1st Place
x 2nd Place
x 3rd Place

However, **{winner}** returns 1st Place, 2nd Place, 3rd Place in the template. **{winner:label}** returns one, two, three. Isn't that backwards?

Additionally, I'm having the same issue with PT multi-select. It saves the appropriate value to the DB, but I have no way of displaying it.

**Code Added**

```
     {exp:channel:entries channel="awards" dynamic="no" limit="1"  disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"} 
    {awards_results} 
        <p>Value: {award-highlight}<br/> Label: {award-highlight:label}</p> 
    {/awards_results} 
 {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Hey Matt, can you add your template code in its entirely please?  And what version of the Field Pack are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the right code for what you want, and will give you the customization you need.  This is from the PT Checkbox docs included in the download for the FieldPack.  I didn't actually see a reference to the :label argument in our docs for Checkbox (though 'tis there for other addons, such as the Dropdowns).  So do please use the variable pair approach:

```
    {exp:channel:entries}
<h1>{title}</h1>
    {pt_check}
    {option_name}: {option}<br />
    {/pt_check}
<hr />
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

{pt_check} is my checkbox field.  So if you're doing this in Matrix, you'll have that inside of your Matrix variable pair.